# $\displaystyle{\limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L = \liminf_{x \to \infty} f(x)}$ proof

Tags: proof-explanation

In the following [link](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-limit-superior-and-limit-inferior-of-functions-of-real-n) at the end of the page there is presented a proof for the following theorem:

> Let $f : (a, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
> $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L}$ if and only if
> $\displaystyle{\limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L = \liminf_{x \to
> > \infty} f(x)}$.

Most of this proof seems to me like it is missing some pieces, for example in the "Hence..." paragraph how does the author conclude this $
\displaystyle{\liminf_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \inf_{t \geq x} \{ f(t) \} = L}$.

Can anyone explain this proof in a little more detail or maybe even show it on concrete example?

Comment: This is the definition. Since $\inf_{t\ge x}\{f(t)\}$ is nondecreasing as $x\to\infty$, we know that the limit exists in $(-\infty,+\infty]$ when $x$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: @Bach In $\begin{align} \quad L - \epsilon \leq \inf_{t \geq x} \{ f(t) \} \leq \sup_{t \geq x} \{ f(t) \} \leq L + \epsilon \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \biggr \lvert \inf_{t \geq x} \{ f(t) \} - L \biggr \rvert < \epsilon \quad , \quad \biggr \lvert \sup_{x \geq t} \{ f(t) \} - L \biggr \rvert < \epsilon \end{align}$ why are there $\leq$ symbols when there should be $<$ ?

Comment: I think they should be $\le$.

Comment: How come if above we have $\begin{align} \quad L - \epsilon < f(x) < L + \epsilon \end{align}$?

Comment: It doesn't matter since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small.

Comment: But it can't be zero. I mean $f(x)$ and $f(t)$ are the same numbers, the symbol should not change.

Comment: That's a typo. Don't care too much about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how their proof goes, let's analyse it line by line:

> **Proof:** $\Rightarrow$ Suppose that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$. Then for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $M \in \mathbb{R}$, $M \geq a$ such that $f(x) - L < \epsilon$.

This is correct, but not complete. What they should have said was

". . .such that $\color{red}{\lvert} f(x) - L \color{red}{\rvert} < \epsilon$."

This is just the definition of limit. In fact, only with this correction does their next sentence make sense:

> So, if $x \geq M$, then $$L - \epsilon < f(x) < L + \epsilon \tag{3}$$

They could not have concluded that $L - \epsilon < f(x)$ just from $f(x) - L < \epsilon$. Moving on,

> So for $x \geq M$ we have that $L + \epsilon$ is an upper bound for $f$ and $L - \epsilon$ is a lower bound for $f$. Thus for $x \geq M$ we have that:
>   $$
> L - \epsilon \leq \inf_{t \geq x}\{ f(t) \} \leq \sup_{t \geq x}\{ f(t) \} \leq L + \epsilon \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \left\lvert \inf_{t \geq x}\{ f(t) \} - L \right\rvert < \epsilon, \left\lvert \sup_{x \geq t}\{f(t)\} - L \right\rvert < \epsilon \tag{4}
> $$

First of all, they have a potentially confusing typo in the last inequality: it should be
$$
\left\lvert \sup_{\color{red}{t \geq x}}\{f(t)\} - L \right\rvert < \epsilon.
$$

Secondly, note that if you have that $L - \epsilon \color{green}{<} f(x)$ for all $x \geq M$, then $L - \epsilon \color{green}{\leq} \inf_{x \geq M}\{f(x)\}$. Think of how analogously you have $\inf\{ x : 2 < x < 3\} = 2$, for example. Similarly, 
if you have that $f(x) \color{green}{<} L + \epsilon$ for all $x \geq M$, then $\inf_{x \geq M}\{f(x)\} \color{green}{\leq} L + \epsilon$.

So, what have they really shown so far? What they have shown is that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a real number $M \geq a$ such that for all $x \geq M$, we have
$$
\left\lvert \inf_{t \geq x}\{ f(t) \} - L \right\rvert < \epsilon
$$
and
$$
\left\lvert \sup_{t \geq x}\{f(t)\} - L \right\rvert < \epsilon.
$$
Hence, if we define the functions $g, h \colon (a,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
g(x) = \inf_{t \geq x}\{ f(t) \} \quad \text{and} \quad h(x) = \sup_{t \geq x}\{f(t)\},
$$
then we have that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x) = L$, by the definition of limit. On the other hand, we also have the definitions for $\limsup$ and $\liminf$, so combining them we get:

> Hence, $\liminf_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \inf_{t \geq x} \{ f(t) \} = L$ and $\limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sup_{t \geq x} \{ f(t) \} = L$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: So basically, it is just observing that $liminf$ and $limsup$ are "fitting into" the definition of a limit and that is enough to prove the theorem?

Comment: @MichaelMunta Yes, I believe you got it.

Comment: @MichaelMunta Just to elaborate, for clarity's sake: we got that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = L$. But, $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \inf_{t \geq x}\{ f(t) \} = \liminf_{x \to \infty} f(x)$. Hence, $\liminf_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$. Similarly, for the other limit.

Comment: not sure what you mean with the last comment?

Comment: @MichaelMunta Let me know what's not clear? I'm elaborating on why $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = L$ implies the quoted line "Hence. . ."

Comment: @MichaelMunta Is the proof okay now?

Comment: how does one conclude that if $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ then $L - \epsilon < f(x) < L + \epsilon$?

Comment: @MichaelMunta From the definition of absolute value, $|a| < b \iff -b < a < b$ (just think about why this is so if it is not immediately clear). So, in our case, we have $-\epsilon < f(x) - L < \epsilon$. Hence, $L - \epsilon < f(x) < L + \epsilon$.